# Socket disconnect as soon as it connects in android

Tags: android, websocket

i am trying to create group chat android application and used Websocket server written in php. this server work fine on Web browser but when i try to use it in android application application disconnect as soon as it connects.

here Android code:

public class MainActivty extends Activity{

```
private WebSocketClient mWebSocketClient;
private ListView mMessageListView;
private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_layout);
    mMessageListView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    mAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    mMessageListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    connectWebSocket();
}

private void connectWebSocket(){
    URI uri;
    try {
        uri=new URI("ws://192.168.0.102:9000");
        mWebSocketClient=new WebSocketClient(uri){

            @Override
            public void onOpen(ServerHandshake serverHandshake) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onMessage(String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onClose(int i, String s, boolean b) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Exception e) {


            }
        };
        mWebSocketClient.connect();
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

}


private void Append_Message(String log){
    mAdapter.add(log);
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

server console:

[server console shows client activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sblZA.png)

Comment: You have no code or logging statements in onOpen(), onMessage(), onError\()  and onClose(). Please add them and report.

Comment: Who do you blame for closing the connection rigth away? Your client ? Your php script?

Answer (score 1):

when i rewrite this code using https://github.com/pavelbucek/tyrus-client-android-test i think i could not satisfied full requirement of previous library that i used. but tutorial on this link have solved my problem.